# Names Scores project euler #22

Tags: python-3.x

## PROJECT EULER PROB. 22: NAMES SCORES

Using names.txt
(LINK : https://projecteuler.net/project/resources/p022_names.txt), a 46K text file containing over five-thousand first names, begin by sorting it into alphabetical order. Then working out the alphabetical value for each name, multiply this value by its alphabetical position in the list to obtain a name score.
For example, when the list is sorted into alphabetical order, COLIN, which is worth `3 + 15 + 12 + 9 + 14 = 53`, is the 938th name in the list. So, COLIN would obtain a score of `938 × 53 = 49714`.
What is the total of all the name scores in the file?

**My output:**

```
811204450
```

[image]

I don't know where I am wrong my answer for "COLIN" is also `49714`, and the names are also sorted properly.

**My code:**

```
d=dict()
j=1
for i in range(ord('A'),ord('Z')+1):
    d[chr(i)]=j
    j+=1

def main():
    global d
    
    print(d)
    f=open("p022_names.txt","r")
    t=f.read()
    
    
    t=t.split(',')
    t.sort()  #THIS IS BUILT IN FN. SORT
    print(t[0:10])  #CHECKING IF EVERYTHING IS SORTED
    tot=0
    l=[]
    i=0
    for i in range(5000):  #THERE ARE 5000 NAMES
        
        for s in t[i]:
            if(s=='"'):
                #print(s)
                continue
            else:
                #print(s)
                tot+=d[s]

        p=(i+1)*tot
        l.append(p)
        
        if(t[i]=='"COLIN"'):
            print(t[i]," i= ",i)
            print("p= ",p," tot= ",tot)
            print(t[i],"  ",l[i])

        tot=p=0

    p=0
    print("len(l) = ",len(l))
    for i in range(len(l)):
        p+=l[i]    
    print("total score= ",p)
                
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

From https://projecteuler.net/problem=22:

> ...a 46K text file containing **over** five-thousand first names...

If you care to check it's **5163**. Just change:

```
for i in range(5000):
```

to

```
for i in range(len(t)):
```

You can also shorten your code using `sum` and generator expressions:

```
t = sorted(name.strip('"') for name in t)
result = sum(sum(ord(c)-64 for c in t[i]) * (i+1) for i in range(len(t)))
```

Comment: Thanks man, it worked , I thought only 5000 names were present ,I didn't read it properly and Iam just a beginner, thanks for your suggestion